# eclipse null analysis field initialization

Tags: eclipse, null, initialization, field, analysis

Using the Null Analysis of Eclipse:

It it possible to define other methods as initializing methods than Constructors?

I have a class like this:

```
public class Foo {

    @NonNull    
    private Object fooObject;

    public Foo() {
        super();
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        fooObject = //Something which is not available in the Constructor;
    }
```

Here i get the warning that the NonNull field may has not been initialized. Is there any possibility to kind of declare the init-method as an initalizing one?

I could use @SuppressWarnings("null") for the constructor. But then I ignore all fields, which may instanciated somewhere.

Second chance i see is to make fooObject as @Nullable - but then i need check for null each time i use fooObject.

So is there any better solution?

Comment: Why would an @Nullable annotation force you to check for null? If you know that onCreate() has been called before, you don't need to check for null. Null analysis is only a tool to help you identify bugs. You should know better then the tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null-checking object initialization beyond the constructor is inherently difficult. Several sophisticated approaches exist, all of which require additional annotations.

In your example it seems to be near-impossible, to prove to the compiler, that onCreate() is always called before accessing the field.

A weaker solution has been proposed: @LazyNonNull, an annotation to be used on fields that are initially null, but once initialized can never go back to null. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=414237

Obviously, a static factory method, that gathers all necessary values before invoking a constructor (with arguments) would be a lot easier to get right.